# Should I avoid multiple connections to same db?

Tags: php

Im testing out PHP-RBAC (a Role Based Access Control system) for PHP. PHP-RBAC doesn't seems to allow me to inject my current PDO object. It creates its own PDO object. This will cause two connections to be established to the same database each call to my page. Is this a problem?

Comment: Most databases will allow multiple connections from a single user at the same time. It will only be an issue if your db is configured to NOT all that.

Comment: I'd avoid using a library which insists on using its own database connection. Doesn't sound like a well written tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem.

I also need to use my own PDO connection, because I'm using MySQL SSL authentication that isn't supported by the library.

To facilitate this I wrote [a fork](https://github.com/Snooze-/rbac) of the project that takes a PDO object as an argument to the constructor. I've submitted a PR to the devs of the project, but they don't seem too interested. [Discussion here](https://github.com/OWASP/rbac/pull/40).

Comment: Nice! Sad they didn't like it :( Unfortunately this database thing makes me stay away from this library until they fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you're going to use non-persistent connections so each thread will make its own connection. From that angle it's not a big deal.

The other end is that you're doing more work now. Each connection takes resources and those resources are finite. So if you've got a site dealing with hundreds of concurrent users, this could pose a problem from a scalability standpoint. The question you have to answer is this: do you expect this site/project to scale to a point to where this could become a problem?